# Measure variation of data points from a line; To Catch a Dip

Tags: c++, plot, statistics, line

## How can I measure this area in C++?

*(update: I posted the solution and code as an answer rather than edit the question again)*

[image: How to quantify the blue area between ideal curve and measured curve]
The ideal line (dashed red) is the plot from starting point with the average rise added with each angle of measurement; this I obtain via average. I measured the test data in black. How can I quantify the area of the dip in blue? X-axis is unitized, so slopes and math are simplified.

I could determine a cutoff for the size of areas like this and then flag this part for retesting or failure. Rarely, there is another dip that appears closer to the right, but setting a cutoff value for standard deviation usually fails those parts.

### Update

Diego's answer helped me visualize this. Now that I can see what I'm trying to do, I'll work on the algorithm to implement the "homemade dip detector". :)
[image: Better visualization of the problem]

---

### Why?

I created a [test bench](https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=36254) to test throttle position sensors I'm selling. I'm trying to programatically quantify how straight the plot is by analyzing the data collected. This one particular model is vexing me.

Sample plot of a part I prefer not to sell:
[image: Test data has a curve in it]

The X axis are evenly spaced angles of throttle opening. The stepper motor turns the input shaft, stopping every 0.75° to measure the output on a 10 bit ADC, which gets translated to the Y axis. The plot is the translation of `data[idx]` to `idx,value` mapped to `(x,y)` bitmap coordinates. Then I draw lines between the points within the bitmap using Bresenham's algorithm.

*My other TPS products produce [amazingly linear output](http://ca-cycleworks.com/media/catalog/product/p/f/pf1c_printout.jpg).*

The lower (left) portion of the plot is crucial to normal usage of any motor vehicle; it's when you're driving around town, entering parking lots, etc. This particular part has a tendency to develop a dip around 15° opening and I wish to use the program to quantify this "dip" in the curve and rely less upon the tester's intuition. In the above example, the plot dips but doesn't return to what an ideal line might be.

Even though this is an embedded application, printing the report takes 10 seconds, thus I do not consider stepping through an array of 120 points of data multiple times a waste of cycles. Also, since I'm using a [uC32 PIC32 microcontroller](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?Prod=CHIPKIT-UC32), there's plenty of memory, so I have the luxury of being able to ponder this problem within the controller.

---

### What I'm trying already

**Array of rise between test points:** I dismiss the X-axis entirely, considering it unitized, and then make an array of change from one reading to the next. This array is what contributes to the report's "Min rise between points: 0 Max: 14". I call this array <kbd>deltas</kbd>.

I've tried using **standard deviation** on <kbd>deltas</kbd>, however, during testing I have found that a low Std Dev is not a reliable measure for this part. If the dip quickly returns to the original line implied by early data points, the Std Dev can be deceptively low (observed to be as low as 2.3) but the part is still something I wouldn't want to use. I tried setting a cutoff at 2.6, but it failed too many parts with great plots. *The other, more linear part linked to above can reliably count on Std Dev for quality.*

**Kurtosis** seems not to apply for this situation at all. I learned of [Kurtosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) today and found a [Statistics Library](http://www.johndcook.com/skewness_kurtosis.html) which includes Kurtosis and Skewness. During continued testing, I found that of these two measures, there was not a trend of positive, negative, or amplitude which would correspond to either passing or failing. That same gentleman has shared a linear regression library, but I believe Lin Reg is unrelated to my situation, as I am comfortable with the assumption of the AVG of <kbd>deltas</kbd> being my ideal line. Linear Regression and R^2 are more for finding a line from less ideal data or much larger sets.

**Comparing each delta to AVG and Std Dev** I set up a monitor to check each delta against final average of the <kbd>deltas</kbd>'s data. Here, too, I couldn't find a reliable metric. Too many good parts would not pass a test restricting any delta to within 2x Std Dev away from the Average. Ultimately, the only variation from AVG I could settle on is to be within `AVG+Std Dev` difference from the AVG itself. Anything more restrictive would fail otherwise good parts. And the elusive dip around 15° opening can sneak through this test.

**Homemade dip detector** When feeding <kbd>deltas</kbd> to the serial monitor of the computer, I observed consecutive negative <kbd>deltas</kbd> during the dip, so I programmed in a dip detector, but it feels very crude to me. If there are 5 or more negative <kbd>deltas</kbd> in a row, I sum them. I have seen that if I take that sum the dip's differences from AVG then divide by the number of negative deltas, a value over 2.9 or 3 could mean a fail. I have observed dips lasting from 6 to 15 deltas. Readily observable dips would have their differences from AVG sum up to -35.

**Trending accumulated variation from the AVG** The above made me think watching the summation of <kbd>deltas</kbd> as it wanders away from AVG could be the answer. Meaning, I step through the array and sum the differences of each delta from AVG. I thought I was on to something until a good part blew this theory. I was seeing a trend of the fewer times the running sum varied from `AVG` by less than `2x AVG`, the more straight the line appeared. Many ideal parts would only show 8 or less delta points where the `sumOfDiffs` would stray from the AVG very far.

```
float sumOfDiffs=0.0;
for( int idx=0; idx<stop; idx++ ){
    float spread = deltas[idx] - line->AdcAvgRise;
    sumOfDiffs = sumOfDiffs + spread;
    ...
    testVal = 2*line->AdcAvgRise;
    if( sumOfDiffs > testVal || sumOfDiffs < -testVal ){
        flag = 'S';
    }
    ...
}
```

And then a part with a fantastic linear plot came through with 58 data points where `sumOfDiffs` was more than twice the AVG! I find this amazing, as at the end of the ~120 data points, `sumOfDiffs` value is -0.000057.

During testing, the final `sumOfDiffs` result would often register as 0.000000 and only on exceptionally bad parts would it be greater than .000100. I found this quite surprising, actually: how a "bad part" can have accumulated great accuracy.

**Sample output from monitoring sumOfDiffs** This below output shows a dip happening. The test watches as the running `sumOfDiffs` is more than 2x the AVG away from the AVG for the whole test. This dip lasts from <kbd>deltas</kbd> `idx` of 23 through 49; starts at 17.25° and lasts for 19.5°.

```
Avg rise: 6.75    Std dev: 2.577
idx: delta  diff from avg   sumOfDiffs  Flag
 23:   5    -1.75           -14.05      S
 24:   6    -0.75           -14.80      S
 25:   7     0.25           -14.55      S
 26:   5    -1.75           -16.30      S
 27:   3    -3.75           -20.06      S
 28:   3    -3.75           -23.81      S
 29:   7     0.25           -23.56      S
 30:   4    -2.75           -26.31      S
 31:   2    -4.75           -31.06      S
 32:   8     1.25           -29.82      S
 33:   6    -0.75           -30.57      S
 34:   9     2.25           -28.32      S
 35:   8     1.25           -27.07      S
 36:   5    -1.75           -28.82      S
 37:  15     8.25           -20.58      S
 38:   7     0.25           -20.33      S
 39:   5    -1.75           -22.08      S
 40:   9     2.25           -19.83      S
 41:  10     3.25           -16.58      S
 42:   9     2.25           -14.34      S
 43:   3    -3.75           -18.09      S
 44:   6    -0.75           -18.84      S
 45:  11     4.25           -14.59      S
 47:   3    -3.75           -16.10      S
 48:   8     1.25           -14.85      S
 49:   8     1.25           -13.60      S
Final Sum of diffs: 0.000030
RunningStats analysis:
NumDataValues= 125
Mean= 6.752
StandardDeviation= 2.577
Skewness= 0.251
Kurtosis= -0.277
```

---

**Sobering note about quality:** what started me on this journey was learning how major automotive OEM suppliers consider a 4 point test to be the standard measure for these parts. My [first test bench](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151332087166366&set=a.10151332087146366.1073741825.144922416365&type=3&theater) used an Arduino with 8k of RAM, didn't have a TFT display nor a printer, and a mechanical resolution of only 3°! Back then I simply tested <kbd>deltas</kbd> being within arbitrary total bounds and choosing a limit of how big any single delta could be. My 120+ point test feels high class compared to that 30 point test from before, but that test had no idea about these dips.

Comment: Hey! Wonderful visualization of what I wrote. It is exactly what I had in my mind (making it horizontal subtracting a linear ideal slope and look at what remains) but I was too lazy to produce also a drawing.

Comment: Was actually very easy to do in Inkscape! :) I turned on grid snaps and cut-pasted the same 3 paths for each step. Hardest part was making the bars on the last frame. I didn't realize this, but my "ratio" was the area divided by number points, so is the average "rise" or magnitude of the dip. I've got some great data to finish a write up with. I'll try to get that updated within a week. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Premises

- the mean of a set of data has the mathematical property that the sum of the deviations from the mean is 0.

  - this explains why both bad and good datasets alwais give almost 0.
  - basically the result when differs from zero is essentially an accumulations of rounding errors in the diffs and that's why unfortunately cannot hold useful informations
- the thing that most clearly define what you're looking for is your image: you're looking for an **AREA** and this is why you're not finding the solution in this ways:

  - looking to a metric in the single points is too local to extract that information
  - looking to global accumulations or parameters (global standard deviation) is too global and you lose the data among too much information and source of variations
  - kurtosis (you've already told I know but is for completeness) is out of its field of applications since this is not a probability distribution
  - in the end the more suitable approach of your already tryied ones is the "Homemade dip detector" because thinks in a way that is local but not too much.
- Last but not least:

  - Any Algorithm you're going to choose has its tacit points on which it stands.

    - So maybe one is looking for a super clever algorithm that with no parametrization and tuning automatically adapts to the problem and self define thereshods and other.
    - On the other side there is an algorithm that will stand on the knowledge by the writer of the tipical data behavior (good and bad) and that is itself stupid in the way that if there is another different and unespected behavior the results are unpredictable
    - Ok, the right way is one of this two or is in-between them depending on the application. So if it works also the "Homemade dip detectors" can be a solution. There is not reason to define it crude but it could be that is not sufficient based on applicaton needs and that's an other thing.

### How to find the area

- Once you have the data the first thing is to clearly define the "theoretical straight line". I give some options:

  - use RANSAC algorithm (**formally** the best option IMHO)

    - this give you the best fit to the aligned points disregarding the not aligned ones
    - it is quite difficult and maybe oversized for this work (IMHO)
  - consider the line defined by the first and last point

    - you told that the dip is almost always in the same position that is not near boundaries so first and last points can be thought as affordable
    - very easy to implement
    - this is an example of using the knowledge about expected behaviors as I told before so you need to think if and how much confidence you give to this assumption
  - consider a linear fit to the first 10 points and last 10 points

    - is only a more affordable version of previous since using more points you can be less worried that maybe just the first point or the last were affected by any measure problem and so all fails because of this
    - also quite easy to implement
    - if I were you I will use this or something inspired to this
- calculate the Y value given by the straight line for each X
- calculate the area between the two curves (or the areas under the function `Y_dev = Y_data - Y_straight` that is mathematically the same) with this procedure:

  - `PositiveMax = 0; NegativeMax = 0;`
  - start from first point (value can be positive or negative) and put in a temporary area accumulator `tmp_Area`
  - for each next point

    - if the sign is the same then accumulate the value
    - if it is different

      - stop accumulating
      - check if the accumulated value is the greater than PositiveMax or below NegativeMax and if it is than store as new PositiveMax or NegativeMax
      - in any case reset the accumulator with `tmp_Area = Y_dev;` to the current value starting this way a new accumulation
  - in the end you will have the values of the maximum overvalued contiguous area and maximum undervalued contiguous area that I think are the scores you're looking for.
  - if you want you can only manage the NegativeMax based on observed and expected data behaviors
  - you may find useful to put a thereshold so that if a value `Y_dev` is lower than the thereshold you do not accumulate it.
  - this in order to not obtain large accumulations from many points close to the straight line that can be similar to the accumulations of few points far from the line

    - the need of this and and the proper thereshold needs to be evaluated on some sample data
  - you need to find an appropriate thereshold for this contiguous area and you can have it only from observation of sample data.

    - again: it can be you observing and deciding the thereshold or you can build a repository of good and bad samples and write a program that automatically learn which thereshold to use. But his is not the algorithm, this is how to find its operative parameters and there is nothing wrong to do by human brain.. ..it only depends if we're looking for a method to separate bad and good things or if we're looking for and autoadaptive algorithm that does this.. ..you decide the target.

Comment: It sounds like you've done this before, thanks for the great info! A plan is forming. I'm currently opening the next (and last) carton of these parts so I've got 70 to test and work with. Yes, I observe the results and adjust parameters as I go. I have a few safeguards in place for when the response is nonsense; they too improve as I go along.

Comment: Not sure if you saw, I added my solution as another answer. Thanks again for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the result of my gut feeling and Diego's method is an average of the integral. I still don't like that name, so I have described the algorithm and have [asked on Math.SE what to call this, which got migrated to "Cross Validated", Stats.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530767) .

I Updated graphs after a massive edit of my Math.SE question. It turns out I'm taking the average of a closed integral of the derivative of the data. :P First, we gather the data:

[image: Plot of data gathered, highlighting the dip]

Next is the "derivative": step through the original data array to form the <kbd>deltas</kbd> array which is the rise of ADC values from one 0.75° step to the next. "Rise" or "slope" is what the derivative is: dy/dx.

With the "slope" or average leveled out, I can find multiple negative <kbd>deltas</kbd>  in a row, sum them, then divide by the count at the end of the dip. The sum is an integral of the area between average and the <kbd>deltas</kbd> and when the dip goes back positive, I can divide the sum by the count of the dips.

[image: Average of the Numerical Integral of the derivative]

During testing, I came up with a cutoff value for this average of the integral at 2.6. That was a great measure of my "gut instinct" looking at the plot thinking a part was good or bad.

In case someone else finds themselves trying to quantify this, here's the code I implemented. Note that it is only looking for negative dips. Also, dipCountLimit is defined elsewhere as 5. In addition to the dip detector/accumulator (ie Numerical Integrator) I also have a spike detector that arbitrarily flags the test as bad if any data points stray from the average by the amount of average + standard deviation. AVG+STD DEV as a spike limit was chosen arbitrarily based on the observed plots of the parts it would fail.

```
int dipdx=0;
//  inDipFlag also counts the length of this dip
int inDipFlag=0;
float dips[140] = { 0.0 };
for( int idx=0; idx<stop; idx++ ){
    const float diffFromAvg = deltas[idx] - line->AdcAvgRise;
    //  state machine to monitor dips
    const int _stop = stop-1;
    if( diffFromAvg < 0 && idx < _stop ) {
        //  check NEXT data point for negative diff & set dipFlag to put state in dip
        const float nextDiff = deltas[idx+1] - line->AdcAvgRise;
        if( nextDiff < 0 && inDipFlag == 0 )
            inDipFlag = 1;
        //  already IN a dip, and next diff is negative
        if( nextDiff < 0 && inDipFlag > 0 ) {
            inDipFlag++;
        }

        //  accumulate this dip
        dips[dipdx]+= diffFromAvg;

        //  next data point ends this dip and we advance dipdx to next dip
        if( inDipFlag > 0 && nextDiff > 0 ) {
            if( inDipFlag < dipCountLimit ){
                //  reset the accumulator, do not advance dipdx to next entry
                dips[dipdx]=0.0;
            } else {
                //  change this entry's value from dip sum to its ratio
                dips[dipdx] = -dips[dipdx]/inDipFlag;
                //  advance dipdx to next entry
                dipdx++;
            }
            //  Next diff isn't negative, so the dip is done
            inDipFlag = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice overview of the solution with very clear images as your usual!
I'm happy to have contributed in the right direction.
My proposal for the name is "Local Mean Deviation".

Comment: @DiegoMazzaro thank you! Actually, I need illustrations to learn & making them clear helped me realize I was differentiating. :)